# How to return a list of value corresponding to repeated keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to return a list of list where each sublist has values corresponding to key words in a dictionary.
E.g:

```
dictionary = {'CORRECT': ['full','mark'],'INCORRECT':['partial','mark']}
```

For a list of lists `[['INCORRECT'],['INCORRECT','CORRECT']]`,it should return:

```
[[['partial','mark']],[['partial','mark'],['full','mark']]]
```

Here's what I'ved tried: (ps: clean_word is a function I used before,please ignore it)

```
result = []
    for key in dictionary:
        word = clean_word(key)

        if word:
           result.append(dictionary[word])

    return result
```

However, this code will return a result like

```
[['full','mark'], ['partial', 'mark']]
```

The order is a mess and it's missing value.
I guess it's because it has a key (INCORRECT) that repeated in the List, so python only looks at the first appearance of the key. How to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want `[['partial','mark'],[['partial','mark'],['full','mark']]]` and not `[[['partial','mark']],[['partial','mark'],['full','mark']]]`? The second makes more sense, output is a list of list_of_lists

Comment: Sorry for the mislead. The output should be a list of list_of_lists. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a list comprehension:

```
l = [['INCORRECT'],['INCORRECT','CORRECT']]
dictionary = {'CORRECT': ['full','mark'],'INCORRECT':['partial','mark']}

[[dictionary[e] for e in i] for i in l]
```

output:

```
[[['partial', 'mark']], [['partial', 'mark'], ['full', 'mark']]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = [['INCORRECT'],['INCORRECT','CORRECT']]
dictionary = {'CORRECT': ['full','mark'],'INCORRECT':['partial','mark']}
result = [ [dictionary[x] for x in sublist ] if isinstance(sublist, list) else dictionary[sublist] for sublist in my_list ]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.